# tabindex is given it is focusing but on enter key enter it won't work

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

When I click on search icon with mouse it works fine , but when i use tab and focus goes to icon but when i enter "ENTER" keyword it won't work .

```
` <%-- Mobile Only - Search Icon --%>
 <div class="mobile-header-icon" onclick="OnClickSearchIcon();" tabindex="0" 
           aria-label="Search">
     <i class="search" ></i>
        </div>`
```

Answer (score 4):

Pressing `enter` does not fire a click event.

You could add a listener for e.g. keyup event.

---

Here is a full working example:

```js
function OnClickSearchIcon(){
  // do whatever you want instead of this
  document.body.innerHTML += "<p>Search!</p>";
}

function onKeyUp(e){
  if (e.key === "Enter") OnClickSearchIcon();
}
```

```html
<div tabindex=0 onkeyup="onKeyUp(event)" onclick="OnClickSearchIcon()" >
  <i class="search" >Click, or focus me and press Enter</i>
</div>
```

Comment: function onKeyUp(e){
    if (e.key === "Enter") OnClickSearchIcon();
}                                                                                                                                             <div class="mobile-header-icon" onclick="onKeyUp();" tabindex="0" 
           aria-label="Search">
     <i class="search" ></i>
        </div>`                                             not working .

Comment: you are calling onKeyUp with no argument. You need to pass the event. Besides, you are using the handler for click instead of keyup: `onkeyup="onKeyUp(event);"`

Comment: Still not working .

Comment: I have added a full working example. Please make sure that the element really gets the focus before pressing `Enter` (it should be somehow highlighted by your browser).

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: onKeyUp is not defined
    at HTMLDivElement.onkeyup            showing me this error on console .

Comment: Have you added the definition of the onKeyUp function in your code, and is it reachable? (should probably be next to `OnClickSearchIcon`). 

Also, please check for spelling mistakes (including uppercase/lowercase).

Lastly, you could alternatively go for: `<div tabindex=0 onkeyup="if (event.key === 'Enter') OnClickSearchIcon();" ... `. 

Without more context, there is nothing more I can do...

Comment: onkeypress() works for me insert of onkeyup().

Comment: Cool! Glad that you have finally made it