# Generic "click" event in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, click

What event should I use in HTML/JavaScript to handle any "click" event that may happen on users platform, no mater what input method user uses?

HTML built-in elements like `<button>` or `<a>` handle any input method available to the use, including "clicking" links with *Tab+Enter* or with touchscreen. However if I use *click* event on any element that is not clickable by default (e.g. a `<span tabindex="0">`), then it's interpreted as mouse only.

I could in theory bind to one of the keyboard events too, but still some new input method may emerge in the future, so I'd prefer using something that would make the browser care about what input devices it handles, not the website. I'm also not sure about the touchscreens.

Comment: I don't think there's a generic event that can be used with elements that you can't focus on.

Comment: Take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71689005/tabindex-is-given-it-is-focusing-but-on-enter-key-enter-it-wont-work